# Trying to combine two table result in single array getting error Cannot use [] for reading

Tags: php, laravel

```
$user1=user1::get();
$user2=user2::get();
$users=array();

foreach ($user1 as $user) {
    $users[]=$user;
}
foreach ($user2 as $user) {
    $users[]=$user;
}
```

i'm fetching data from two tables and want to do some process on both results so instead of processing them separately i thought of adding them in single array and then do the processing but getting the error **Cannot use [] for reading** how can i do this.

Comment: Can't you just do array_merge($user1, $user2) ?

Comment: Yes, and that code does not generate that error.

Comment: Does `array_merge()` function solve your problem? `array_merge($user1, $user2);`

Comment: You have 2 Collections, which contain arrays of items .. you can get those arrays from them `$user1->all()` if you want the array then you can merge them .. you can merge the collections themselves, but you would want to convert them to base collections first

Comment: Is the error in this file or is it when you're trying to output the data? "for reading" sounds more like output than assigning values.

Comment: Do you have a `User` model? If so, then you dont need to merge, just use `whereIn` in your query.

Comment: You have array_merge yes and you can also do : `$user = $user1 + $user2`

Comment: If your'e going to simplify code you have a problem with make sure it actually still has the problem. [this sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/88eb850b9ac74f12a1f4e7539034ceb391c33168) works just file for me and I have also tried it on a local laravel project I have and it also works.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use like this

```
$users=array();

foreach ($user1 as $user) {
    array_push ($users,$user);
}

foreach ($user2 as $user) {
    array_push ($users,$user);
}
```